# How include aar whitch has JNI so file in React Native project

Tags: react-native, java-native-interface, aar

I have wrote a project by React Native,now I need to reference a android SDK to implement some functions.
the android sdk is a aar file,and it contains JNI,now it reports  couldn't find "libjniload.so", the "libjniload.so" is in the aar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference an Android SDK, you must add the files to your android project in your react native project. That means, you must add the dependencies to your build.gradle, and copy the files to you libs folder etc.. This is not any different than adding .aar files to an Android project. After this, you will need to implement a [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android) to call its functions from react-native. This is the general procedure, what exact step is causing error?